# Flex AMFPHP site worked in WAMP 2.2 but fails in WAMP 2.4

Tags: php, actionscript, flex3, wamp, amfphp

I previously implemented a website using Flex 3 and AMFPHP 1.9 served by WAMP 2.2.  When I upgraded to WAMP 2.4, my website no longer worked, with error "send failed".  I had previously defined my `remoteObject` in my `.as` file with a url endpoint and did not use `services-config.xml`.  What would be the most straightforward way to get my site working in the new version of WAMP?  I am open to upgrading AMFPHP 2.2, switching to Zend, switching to a URLRequest, or other options?

Thanks and please let me know if I should supply additional information!

Comment: wats your PHP version

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do regardless of what solution you end up taking is getting more info on what's going wrong.

Here is a good starting point:
http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/

On upgrading: Amfphp 1.9 is long gone and doesn't work with recent version of PHP. The easiest thing to do short term is to try to just fix the bug and limp along with Amfphp 1.9. However if you would like for your software to last you'll need to upgrade sooner or later.